# How to change this complex function to a simple redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, jigoshop

I have been making some changes to a wordpress ecommerce plugin and I've taken out a ton of functions to make it simpler for my needs. Now it won't redirect to the thankyou page after the purchase button is pressed because the function uses some variables that I got rid of like  `order_id`, etc.

I've been working on this for a few hours now, and all I want it to do is redirect to thankyou.php on the click of the purchase button. (I know right now it uses ajax, and I wouldn't mind using it too) I don't need it to go to the processpayment function or anything like that. Really simple.

Here is the code and the functions that I'm working with:

Thanks so much!!!

Input element:

```
<div id="payment">

        <div class="form-row">

            <noscript><?php _e('Since your browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled, please ensure you click the <em>Update Totals</em> button before placing your order. You may be charged more than the amount stated above if you fail to do so.', 'jigoshop'); ?><br/><input type="submit" class="button-alt" name="update_totals" value="<?php _e('Update totals', 'jigoshop'); ?>" /></noscript>

            <?php jigoshop::nonce_field('process_checkout')?>
            <input type="submit" class="button-alt" name="place_order" id="place_order" value="<?php _e('Next Step', 'jigoshop'); ?>" />

            <?php do_action( 'jigoshop_review_order_before_submit' ); ?>

            <?php if (get_option('jigoshop_terms_page_id')>0) : ?>
            <p class="form-row terms">
                <label for="terms" class="checkbox"><?php _e('I accept the', 'jigoshop'); ?> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_option('jigoshop_terms_page_id')); ?>" target="_blank"><?php _e('terms &amp; conditions', 'jigoshop'); ?></a></label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="terms" <?php if (isset($_POST['terms'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> id="terms" />
            </p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action( 'jigoshop_review_order_after_submit' ); ?>

        </div>

    </div>
```

checkout.class.php:

```
        // Process Payment
                    $result = $available_gateways["cheque"]->process_payment( $order_id );


                    // Redirect to success/confirmation/payment page

                        if (is_ajax()) : 
                            ob_clean();
                            echo json_encode($result);
                            exit;
                        else :
                            wp_safe_redirect( $result['redirect'] );
                            exit;
                        endif;


                else :

                    // No payment was required for order
                    $order->payment_complete();

                    // Empty the Cart
                    jigoshop_cart::empty_cart();

                    // Redirect to success/confirmation/payment page
                    $checkout_redirect = apply_filters( 'jigoshop_get_checkout_redirect_page_id', get_option( 'jigoshop_thanks_page_id' ) );
                    if (is_ajax()) : 
                        ob_clean();
                        echo json_encode( array( 'redirect' => get_permalink( $checkout_redirect ) ) );
                        exit;
                    else :
                        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( $checkout_redirect ) );
                        exit;
                    endif;

                endif;

                // Break out of loop
                break;
```

process payment function:

```
function process_payment() {


        // Remove cart
        jigoshop_cart::empty_cart();

        // Return thankyou redirect
        $checkout_redirect = apply_filters( 'jigoshop_get_checkout_redirect_page_id', get_option( 'jigoshop_thanks_page_id' ) );
        return array(
            'result'    => 'success',
            'redirect'  => add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, add_query_arg('order', $order_id, get_permalink( $checkout_redirect )))
        );

    }
```

Here is the error details I'm getting from firebug:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After I turned debugging on, I got these errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_enabled in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php
>   on line 710
>
> Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_enabled in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php
>   on line 710
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PLUGIN_URL - assumed 'PLUGIN_URL' in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-fonts/google-fonts.php
>   on line 81
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PLUGIN_PATH - assumed 'PLUGIN_PATH'
>   in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-fonts/google-fonts.php
>   on line 82
>
> Notice: Undefined index: host in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php
>   on line 2306
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-first_name in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 198
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-last_name in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 199
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-company in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 200
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-address in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 201
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-address-2 in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 202
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-city in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 203
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-state in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 204
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-postcode in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 205
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-country in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 206

IMPORTANT:

> Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 211
>
> Notice: Undefined index: order_comments in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 256
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-company in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 264
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-address in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 265
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-address-2 in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 266
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-city in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 267
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-postcode in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 268
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-country in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 269
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-state in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 270
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-phone in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 272
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping_method in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 282
>
> Notice: Undefined index: payment_method in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 283
>
> Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_edit in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/aioseop.class.php
>   on line 1105
>
> Notice: Undefined index: nonce-aioseop-edit in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/aioseop.class.php
>   on line 1106

IMPORTANT:

> Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 364
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: available_gateways in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 379

IMPORTANT:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function process_payment() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 379
>
> Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_enabled in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php
>   on line 710
>
> Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_enabled in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php
>   on line 710
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PLUGIN_URL - assumed 'PLUGIN_URL' in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-fonts/google-fonts.php
>   on line 81
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PLUGIN_PATH - assumed 'PLUGIN_PATH'
>   in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-fonts/google-fonts.php
>   on line 82
>
> Notice: Undefined index: host in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php
>   on line 2306
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-first_name in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 198
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-last_name in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 199
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-company in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 200
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-address in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 201
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-address-2 in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 202
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-city in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 203
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-state in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 204
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-postcode in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 205
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping-country in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 206
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 211
>
> Notice: Undefined index: order_comments in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 256
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-company in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 264
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-address in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 265
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-address-2 in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 266
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-city in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 267
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-postcode in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 268
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-country in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 269
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-state in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 270
>
> Notice: Undefined index: billing-phone in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 272
>
> Notice: Undefined index: shipping_method in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 282
>
> Notice: Undefined index: payment_method in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 283
>
> Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_edit in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/aioseop.class.php
>   on line 1105
>
> Notice: Undefined index: nonce-aioseop-edit in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/aioseop.class.php
>   on line 1106
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 364
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: available_gateways in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 379

IMPORTANT!!!!:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function process_payment() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php
>   on line 379
>
> Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_enabled in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php
>   on line 710
>
> Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_enabled in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php
>   on line 710
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PLUGIN_URL - assumed 'PLUGIN_URL' in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-fonts/google-fonts.php
>   on line 81
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PLUGIN_PATH - assumed 'PLUGIN_PATH'
>   in
>   /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-fonts/google-fonts.php
>   on line 82

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Use FireBug to debug the ajax request http://getfirebug.com/ It should print out error message of what's went wrong.

Comment: @satrun77 Getting an error on jigoshop-checkout function.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr can you post the complete error message with all the details. Error in which file, line number, error message, and the response text from the ajax request.

Comment: @satrun77 done. That's what I'm getting from firebug

Comment: Hmm, hard to test, I get this: *"We Apologize
Online ordering is currently unavailable. We will notify you as soon as it is."* - probably this of my plugins is useful in your case: http://hakre.wordpress.com/plugins/better-http-redirects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be some text or json string in the response tab, but it's empty. This could be a result of php error that is hidden because of php settings in your server is set to hide all error messages, which is good.

Turn the debugging on see http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug and try again. There should be some text in the response tab.

**Update turn debugging on:**

Something does not look right here. Do you get these errors when you send the Ajax request?

Looking at these errors I can see you have fatal error which must have stopped the code execution.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function process_payment() on a non-object in /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php on line 379
```

You have modified the original file jigoshop_checkout.class.php so it is hard for me to find the exact lines for these errors. But "Notice: Undefined index: " means there is an array variable in that line does not have an index of...

The method 'process_payment' called once in this file

```
// Process Payment
$result = $available_gateways[$this->posted['payment_method']]->process_payment( $order_id );
```

$available_gateways is an array with objects of different payment methods. But there is no object for the payment method defined in $this->posted['payment_method']

Also, I can see there is another error message  state that the variable $available_gateways does not exists/defined

```
Notice: Undefined variable: available_gateways in /home2/findmyki/public_html/bolistylus/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/classes/jigoshop_checkout.class.php on line 379
```

This variable can only be defined when jigoshop_cart::needs_payment() return true

```
if (jigoshop_cart::needs_payment()) :
        // Payment Method
        $available_gateways = jigoshop_payment_gateways::get_available_payment_gateways();
        if (!isset($available_gateways[$this->posted['payment_method']])) :
                jigoshop::add_error( __('Invalid payment method.','jigoshop') );
        else :
                // Payment Method Field Validation
                $available_gateways[$this->posted['payment_method']]->validate_fields();
        endif;
endif;
```

Comment: I turned on debugging and get the above errors right on the website.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="location.href='thankyou.php';">
```

If you don't need it to do anything else try that.  You may need to edit the href to go where you want it to go.  It worked for me on my site.

Also you can always have the action of the form redirect to another page then that page redirects to thank you page after processing.

Just use header('Location: '); to redirect.